# How do I find out the height of the tab bar in a QTabWidget?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyside, qtabwidget

I've created a QTabWidget with images overlaid but the images start at the top of the TabWidget instead of the Tab. I want these images on top of each tab so I need to find out the size of the tab bar to adjust the images down correctly.

Currently on my computer the Tab height is 18 pixels but I need to make sure the adjustment will work across all platforms so is there any way to find out the height of the tabs as a variable?

To clarify - H, the height of the tab bar is what I'm after.
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try, this might give your ans

```
self.widget.geometry().height() - self.any_tab_name.geometry().height()
```

Second portion will give height of tabs("Demo","tab_name"), subtract that from tabwidget height.

Comment: This gives the size of the entire widget, but I just want the size of the tab bar at the top, is there any way to find this specifically?

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you, I have updated the description to show the exact bit of information I'm after. The code you provided gives the height of the entire widget, whereas I am only after the height of the actual tab selection bar.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer without using the difference between 2 heights as follows:

```
print self.widgetName.tabBar().geometry().height()
```

returns the height in pixels of the tab bar. This also allows for different tab content sizes

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `Pyqt5` example for you reference.

```
tabs = QTabWidget()
H = tabs.tabBar().size().height()
```